# How to read JSON file containing multiple dictionaries with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have several JSON files containing **multiple dictionaries** stored in S3. I need to access each line and rename some of the keys. I have written the code in my local environment which works flawlessly, but I run into issues using Lambda. Usually, I get an `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes` error.

Example JSON:

```
{
 "request": 123,
 "key1": [
   {
    "timestamp_unix": 98321,
    "key_2": "Portugal"
   }
  ]
}
{
 "request": 456,
 "key1": [
   {
    "timestamp_unix": 35765,
    "key_2": "China"
   }
  ]
}
```

Local code:

```
import json

with open("myfile.json", "r") as f:
    my_file = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
for j in my_file:
    j[key1][0][key2] = j[key1][0].pop("key_2")
```

AWS code:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")

obj = s3.Object("my-bucket", "path_to/myfile.json")
json_string = obj.get()["Body"].read().decode("utf-8") # this is where my json object is read in with single quotes instead of double quotes
my_file = [json.loads(line) for line in json_string] # error error error
```

I also tried:

```
import boto3
import json

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="my-bucket", Key="path_to/myfile.json")
json_string = obj["Body"].read().decode() # this is where my json object is read in with single quotes instead of double quotes
my_file = [json.loads(line) for line in json_string] # error error error
```

I removed the encode() option altogether, but this didn't work either. I don't want to/can't change the underlying json files and store the dicts in a list.

How can I read in json files with multiple dictionaries with boto3?

Comment: Use `for line in json_string.splitlines()`

Comment: Then I get `"String indices must be integers"` for the next operation which is where I am trying to access a key in the dictionary. I have added it to the original post.

Comment: How did your JSON strings get enclosed in single quotes instead of double quotes? No JSON encoder will do that.

Comment: If it's not valid JSON, you're just in a heap of trouble.

Comment: It's valid JSON. It works in my local environment with the exact same files.

Comment: The question says "# this is where my json object is read in with single quotes instead of double quotes"

Comment: Can you add an example of `json_string` to the question?

Comment: You could try using `obj["Body"].iter_lines()` to iterate over lines in the body.

Comment: You're right, when I print `json_string`, it shows double quotes. I assumed it changed them to single quotes.

Comment: Yes! `obj["Body"].iter_lines()` did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boto3 equivalent of `for line in f:` is to use the `iter_lines()` method.

```
lines = obj.get()["Body"]
my_file = [json.loads(line) for line in lines.iter_lines()]
```